# RESTFul web service with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, rest

Can I user post method both for create and update?

I have tried "PUT" method for updating resources, but I am not getting the parameters on server side.

Answer (score 1):

PUT isn't handled natively through PHP (i.e. $_PUT) nor through CodeIgniter.  Two things to do off of the top of my head: 1) Grab the PUT variables youreself  or 2) Use Phil Sturgeon's REST library.

```
//put an associative array into $post_vars variable
parse_str(file_get_contents("php://input"),$post_vars);
```

Source: http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2008/accessing-incoming-put-data-from-php

However, since you are working with CodeIgniter, you should use Phil Sturgeon's library if you can't find a genuine reason not to.  It's tried, true, and tested and handles all of the HTTP verbs.

https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restserver

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Due to lack of consistent client implementations for PUT or DELETE methods, standard practice is to send a POST request and either A) use a query string parameter (i.e. `?_method=PUT`) or B) send an `X-METHOD-OVERRIDE` header.

(Quick Google search returned this: http://www.endurasoft.com/Blog/post/X-HTTP-Method-Override.aspx)

You would probably need to extend the CI_Input class to know the difference between a create action and an update.

Comment: Hi Landons how can I parse this response in php? i have tried 


$result = $ex->getResponse();

$xmlObj = simplexml_load_string($result);
echo $tracks = $xml->item->company_name;

but getting a null